# What is the ^= operator in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have come across some JS/jQuery code and am trying to find out what the ^= operator means. I can't find anything like this when Googling it.

The HTML page contains a form with these input fields:

```html
<input type="text" id="name" name="name[1]" value="" size="22"/>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name[2]" value="" size="22"/>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name[3]" value="" size="22"/>
```

The JS validates the form before sending it to the server. Can somebody explain to me how the jQuery selector that is used in the lines with `val` and `each` works (or point me to the documentation)?

```js
jQuery("button#finish").click(function(e) {
  var error = false;
  e.preventDefault();
  if (jQuery("[name^=name]").val() != "" ) {
    jQuery("[name^=name]").each(function(){ 
      if (jQuery(this).val() == "") { jQuery(this).closest("tr").remove(); }
    }); 
    
    if ( ! error) { jQuery("#form_names").submit(); }
  }
  else { alert("Bitte mindestens eine Person zuoberst in das Formular eintragen."); }

  });
```

Comment: That's _not_ JavaScript or jQuery, it's an attribute selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`jQuery()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) function (and it's alias the `$()` function) take a [CSS selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/#selectors) as an argument to determine which element(s) to operate on. [The list of supported selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) is given in the jQuery API documentation.

Here, the selector `[foo^="bar"]` means:

> [an] element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"